# List all the available / installed Fonts in the System

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I am trying to list all the available Fonts in the system with dropdown list. Mainly, I got to show `Arial Bold` font in the dropdown list and I have installed the same in my system. But the problem is, My Font `Arial Bold` is not getting populated in the list of available fonts.

**Code**

```
InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();
var fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
foreach (FontFamily font in fontFamilies)
{
  ddllblFontFamilyHead.Items.Add(font.Name);
}
```

I am using the above fonts to apply to `iTextSharp` PDF library to design my pdf content.

**Code for applying Fonts to PDF file**

```
var fontHeader = FontFactory.GetFont(_label.SFontName == null ? "Arial" : _label.SFontName, BaseFont.CP1250, true, _label.SFontSize == null ? 10 : _label.SFontSize.Value, 0);
```

Any help to this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did u watch the variable `fontFamilies` for the value 'Arial Bold'

Comment: Yes, `fontFamilies` did not pickup any value as like `Arial Bold`.

Answer (score 0):

**tested solution**

```
InstalledFontCollection fontCol = new InstalledFontCollection();
for (int x = 0; x <= fontCol.Families.Length-1;x++ )
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fontCol.Families[x].Name);
}
```

Comment: The variable `fonts` cannot be enumerated. ie, Cannot apply foreach with `FontFamily` to enumerate all the fonts.

Comment: I have posted a tested solution, i get every font installed . all variants of Arial, Helevitica , etc....

Comment: No, Still I am not able to get all the `Font` variants of `Arial` etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's a class named `FontFactory` in iTextSharp. This class only contains the standard Type 1 fonts by default, but you can register font directories to add more fonts.

For instance:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectories();
```

The `RegisterDirectories()` method will look at all the usual directories where your operating system stores fonts. This won't capture all the fonts, but you can add additional directories where you know there are fonts:

```
FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(myFontFolder);
```

You can then get all the names of the registered fonts like this:

```
foreach (String f in FontFactory.RegisteredFonts) {
    listBox1.Items.Add(f);
}
```